# I can't find the mistake in my for loop code in r

Tags: r, loops

I have this code:

```
test_x <- 2000

#functions used:

`%+<-%` = function(e1,e2) eval.parent(substitute(e1 <- e1 + e2))

CreateData <- function()
{
numeric(test_x)
}

#variables

test_sum <- 0
test_q <- 0
test_q <- CreateData()
test_Q <- 0
test_Q <- CreateData()
test_step <- 0.01

#two for loops

for (i in test_x) {
  test_q[i] <- 40
}
for (i in (test_x - 1):0) {
  test_sum %+<-% (test_q[i]*test_step)
  test_Q[i] <- test_sum
}
```

I'm expecting that the first for loop would fill test_q with 40 in each of the 2000 locations, but instead each spot is zero.
The second loop thus also stays zero.

No errors. What did I do wrong?

Comment: you are doing `for (i in test_x)`, but `x_test = 2000` so you're only doing `for (i in 2000)` so `i` will only take the value `2000`, you have to do `for (i in 1:test_x)`

Comment: You're totally right. Not sure how I didn't see that. If you post that as a solution I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop `i` is only taking the value 2000, then you should modify the first loop as follows :

```
for (i in 1:test_x) {
  test_q[i] <- 40
}
```